# Euclidean Algorithm in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, discrete-mathematics

Hi I am trying to write Euclidean's Alg. in Python using the concept that a = b*k + r. It works partially in some cases but it messes up near the end. Can someone help me figure out where i made an error?

```py
a = int(input("Enter First Number: "))
b = int(input("Enter Second Number: "))
A = a
B = b
k = 0
r = 1

while (a!=(b*b)):  
    
    while(a>(b*k)):
        k = k+1
        
    k = k-1
    
    r = (a-(b*k))
    a = b
    b = r
  
    print (a,b) #to debug which step it is at
    
print("gcd(",A,",",B,") =",b)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of how the algorithm is supposed to work? And some example cases of (a,b) where it fails?

Comment: `it messes up near the end`: This is not the best problem description.

Comment: If `a = b*k` then you will have found the solution, but your code will still go to force a solution where `a=b*(k-1) + b` where `b=r`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read what you were trying to do but I strongly recommend you to read again the definition of the [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Euclidean%20algorithm,them%20both%20without%20a%20remainder.) in order to start coding it. What you attempted to do is messing with the definition of `k` and k is causing your code to loop in an overextended way.

A simple way to code the Euclidean algorithm is using the division-based implementation of it. Just keep in your mind what the [modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_(modular_arithmetic)) represents and you are ready to go.

Happy learning.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the advice guys, I was able to make the changes and figured it out.
I'll post my solution if anyone wants it for reference.

```
a = int(input("Enter First Number: "))
b = int(input("Enter Second Number: "))
A = a
B = b

while ((a%b)!=0):  
    K = (a/b)
    k = math.trunc(K)   
    r = (a-(b*k))
    a = b
    b = r
        
print("gcd(",A,",",B,") =",b)
```